# How to downgrade mongo db version 4.20 to 3.6 in aws?

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, dockerfile

I am getting the following error while saving,
"Unknown modifier: $pushAll. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array"
I asked the expert, they suggest to downgrade the version of MongoDB.
My current version is v4.2 and needs to be changed to v3.4.

I have tried following command but got error.

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

Error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Invalid command argument. Expected '4.2' or '4.0', found 3.6 in: { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"3.6\", lsid: { id: UUID(\"b146274a-8229-4e16-aec6-bfd13bebca83\") }, $db: \"admin\" }. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-feature-compatibility.",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MongoDB 3.6 release notes regarding `$pushAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/index.html#remove-pushall-update-operator):

> MongoDB 3.6 removes the deprecated $pushAll operator. The operator has been deprecated since 2.4.
>
> Instead of $pushAll, use the $push operator with the $each modifier.

The example quoted:

```
db.students.update(
   { name: "joe" },
   { $push: { scores: { $each: [ 90, 92, 85 ] } } }
)
```

That is, the best way to fix this is to replace `$pushAll` in your code to the form in the example. They both do the same thing, so it's a direct replacement.

If you cannot modify the code, then it's more complicated. Downgrading between more than one major versions is not a supported path. From 4.2.0, you can downgrade to 4.0, but not to 3.4 (which is 3 major versions behind).

Since you cannot downgrade from 4.2.0 to 3.4, you would need to dump the current content of the database, install 3.4, then restore the data. Having said that, downgrading to cater for a removed feature is *never* a good idea.

Note that MongoDB 3.4 series will not be supported anymore [past January 2020](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy), so installing 3.4 is not a good long-term solution.